# Language in Geonames

Tags: php, geonames

I am trying to retrieve some data from GeoNames.org by using the following test URL:

> http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=username&lang=en&country=DE,NL

The data is something as this:

```
{
  "geonames" : [
    {
      ...
      "languages" : "de",
      ...
      "countryName" : "Germany",
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
      "languages" : "nl-NL,fy-NL",
      ...
      "countryName" : "Netherlands",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything seems quite normal, but I also need the language of each country. In the list there is a field which says 'languages' which I thought I could use, but the actual data is unreliable. Sometimes it is normal like 'de' for Germany, but for the Netherlands it is 'nl-NL,fy-NL'.

I am looking for the language 'nl', but how do I know which language I need for every country? And where can I get a name for the language like 'German' and 'Dutch'? I am using PHP, so maybe there is a way to fetch the right information?

Answer (score 0):

Languages field is a comma separated list of language definition, each composed by a 2-letter ISO 639 language code and an optional 2-letter ISO 3166 country code.

You can find a [list of all the ISO languages](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/iso-languagecodes.txt) directly from the geonames websites; this list contains other language code (e.g. 3 letter code) and the language name you are looking for.

The list of languages is ordered, so that the language which comes first are the official/most spoken language, so you can just filter the first language. This is suboptimal of course, since there are countries with multiple official languages such us Switzerland; for this country you could find the first language, plus all the language with explicit country specialization (i.e. fr-CH, it-CH, de-CH)